# With capacitor ,how to lock Home Menu

Tags: javascript, android, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I use capacitor to build a android App,i want stop event about Home , Menu ,when i click Home Menu,the App will not be stop. please help me!

I had used @capacitor/app,but it can't do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.